# get the relative items and outout it as links

Tags: php, mysql

**table1** : `products` has the fields:

```
products_id
products_price
products_status = 1( In Stock )
products_url
```

**table2** : `products_description` has the fields:

```
products_id(equals products_id in table products )
products_name
```

I want to get five relative products name(in stock) and its price, which matches by some part of the products name. 
For example, the product name is `$product_name`. I want to get five relative products name(in stock) and its price.

```
$query = "select products_id , products_price, products_name
          from products p
          left join products_description pd on  p.products_id=pd.products_id and products_status = 1 and ....";`
```

The match like this: if a product name is `True Blood Season 1 DVD`  I want to show five items which begin with "True Blood Season ". the products name maybe others. it not only  True Blood Season

How do I write this in SQL?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE products_name LIKE 'True Blood Season%' LIMIT 5;`? How did you write the query with left joins etc if you can't do that?

Comment: i am sorry, i make an example, the products_name maybe others,

Comment: I don't really know what that means. You won't be able to automatically select out 'related products' based on the selected products' name. This would have to be a separate query after you know which portion of the name to use.

Comment: i mean there are many product name on my site, in your sql command, you have fixed the product name( LIKE 'True Blood Season%')

Comment: why won't be able to automatically select out 'related products' based on the selected products' name. thank you

Comment: You won't be able to do it because if you pull out 'True Blood Season 1 DVD' you could only pull out the same thing, unless you did a substring or something on the selected name, but it wouldn't work very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `products_id`, `products_price`, `products_name` FROM `products` p
LEFT JOIN `products_description` pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
WHERE `products_name` LIKE 'True Blood Season%' AND `products_status` = 1 
ORDER BY `products_name` LIMIT 5;
```

Should be something like the above, but that is just off the top of my head.

Comment: i am sorry, i make an example, the products_name maybe others,

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are looking for, do you need to retrieve different values?

Comment: i mean there are many product name on my site, in your sql command, you have fixed the product name( LIKE 'True Blood Season%')

Comment: Then when you are constructing your query in PHP, you need to substitute the product name in the query. 
 `...WHERE products_name LIKE '".$dbConn->quote($yourSearchName)."%'...`
 etc. The $dbConn->quote() is to help protect against sqlinjection, more info available here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php (this is if you are using PDO). There are other methods available for mysqli